# How can I install Google's proprietary apps on a device running Android 13 Go Edition, particularly an IoT smart module?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-go

I recently acquired an IoT smart module running on Android 13 Go Edition, and it doesn't come pre-installed with Google's proprietary apps like Play Store and Play Services. I'm specifically interested in installing only the necessary apps to run the Play Store. I attempted to install Google Play Services and the Play Store APK using the adb install command, but unfortunately, when I try to open the Play Store, it crashes. Are there specific steps or considerations I should be aware of to successfully install and run these apps on an Android Go device? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I am unable to download APK files from WebView Browser Tester. And I don't know if its ok to directly download the Play Services and Play Store. I want full-fledged support for all the Google apps.